# How to send the java string as input from java to gnuplot?

Tags: java, gnuplot

I use this code to open gnuplot from java, but I don't know how to send the following java string as input to gnuplot:

```
sp 'F:\DataJava\PDE\EqStringSin.dat' w l
```

My class:

```
public class executeCommand {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("wgnuplot");
      Process p = pb.start(); // Start the process.
      p.waitFor(); // Wait for the process to finish.
      System.out.println("Script executed successfully");
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get output stream from process and write to it your input:

```
new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()).write("sp 'F:\DataJava\PDE\EqStringSin.dat' w l\n");
```

Comment: I did it , but it didn't work :
`Process p = pb.start(); // Start the process.
   new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()).write("sp 'F:\\DataJava\\PDE\\EqStringSin.dat' w l");`
   `